# Creating youtube thumbnails on external website

Tags: youtube, thumbnails

I am building a website with software called serif.  Basically, a drag and drop type of package.

What I would like to do is have a homepage with thumbnails from youtube videos so that when users click on the thumbnail, it will allow them to view the video on a larger screen within a different page.

Is there any way I can create quality thumbnails for this purpose?

I have seen website that automatically create thumbnails or alternatively I could right click/save on the thumbnail from youtube and use this image with a hyperlink to the page I require.  Would this be okay with google's TOS??

Many Thanks,

Dave

Comment: did you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**To link from an icon, picture, or inline player**:

```
From the Quick Build tab (Media category), click  Sound or Video and then click on your page.
- or -
Choose Media from the Insert menu and select either Sound... or Video... from the submenu.

Select your media location, either available locally (File) or via the Internet (URL).

Enable File, then click Browse... to locate and select the media file. If you do not wish to embed the file, uncheck Embed sound file in site (or picture equivalent). Click Export Options... if you want to choose how the file is published to the web.

- or -

Enable URL, then enter (or type) the absolute web address for the file. You could paste in the target's URL (using Paste from clipboard), if it already exists on the Internet—ensure you copy the exact URL of the file rather than that of just the website.

Select a link display option (icon, inline, or picture).

Click OK to close the dialog, then click (or click and drag) with the cursor to place the icon, picture, or marker on your page.

If you choose not to embed your source files, we suggest you keep them together in a single subfolder, named "Media" or the like. When you publish your site, WebPlus exports and copies both embedded and non-embedded files into a common folder.
```

**To add linked sound or video to a selected object or hotspot:**

```
For a hyperlink object, select a portion of text, picture or page object and then click  Hyperlink on the Web Properties toolbar.
- or -
For a hotspot, select Hotspot from the Insert menu and then click and drag on your page.

In the dialog, select File to create a hyperlink to a sound (or video) file on your hard disk.

Click Browse..., locate and select the media file, and click Open.

If you do not wish to embed the file, uncheck Embed file in site.

(Optional) Set Export Options... to define an exported file name and physical location. (See Setting image export options)

In the dialog's Target Window tab, a range of target windows or frames can be chosen depending on how you want the link destination to be displayed. (See Adding hyperlinks and actions).

Click OK.
```

**REFER** -
http://www.serif.com/appresources/WPX6/Tutorials/en-gb/help/adding_sound_and_video.htm